# Select all data which is associated in and combination

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table `documents` and table `labels`. I've a third table for the many-to-many association called `doc_labels`.

I've problems to build my SQL statement to select all documents that are accociated with `label1` and `label2`

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM documents d RIGHT JOIN doc_labels dl
ON(d.id = dl.doc_id)
WHERE dl.label_id = 1 AND dl.label_id = 2
```

This statement will return nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM documents d RIGHT JOIN doc_labels dl
ON(d.id = dl.doc_id)
WHERE dl.label_id = 1 OR dl.label_id = 2
```

This statement will return alle documents with the `label1` OR `label2`

How can I select all documents with `label1` AND `label2`.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT * FROM documents d
RIGHT JOIN doc_labels dl
ON(d.id = dl.doc_id)
WHERE dl.label_id IN(1,2)
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dl.label_id) >= 2 /*this will give you the documents that must have lable 1,2 and can have more lables*/
```

Or if you need the documents with only label 1 and 2 then change

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dl.label_id) = 2
```

Comment: @shree.pat18 due to the use of aggregate function `count()`

Comment: Which begs the question, why aggregate functions when all OP wants is simply the required rows?

Comment: @shree.pat18 there is a many-to-many association and using join will give the reaped row for each documents depends on the no of associations each document have , so group by with count and with having filter will check the count for each document i hope it makes sense